# Apache 500 when proxying URLS with %20 via mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, 500-error

We are receiving a 500 out of Apache while proxying calls to tomcat when there is an encoded space in the URL.

We are migrating an application that ran fine on a J2EE container which had an older, integrated version of Apache (1.x), but as soon as we moved the application to Tomcat + Apache 2 + mod_proxy, we began seeing the error.

For instance:

```
http://foo.org/app/rest/no_spaces/  works fine
http://foo.org/app/rest/no%20spaces fails with a 500
```

The request works fine if we hit tomcat directly, and we know that it is not reaching the servlet when going through Apache.

Proxy configuration is as follows for the server that lives on foo.org:

```
ProxyPass /app ajp://127.0.0.1:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app ajp://127.0.0.1:8080/app
```

We tried switching to HTTP rather than AJP with no change in the error.

The leading theory is that mod_proxy is decoding the %20 and then expecting to see other HTTP header info rather than the remaining URL substring and is resulting in a 500.  If this is the case, does anyone have a workaround that does not involve rewriting the app.  If this is not the cause, does anyone have a suggestion as to what it could be?

I have seen no documentation or bug reports of this exact symptom in my searches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm curious if the error still occurs if you use an `http://` proxy instead of the `ajp://`?  That module can be a little problematic.  Also, anything in the apache error.log?

Comment: We tried using http:// and it still failed with the same error. Nothing in the error log either

Answer (score 1):

Does adding 'nocanon' to your ProxyPass rule work?

i.e.
ProxyPass /app ajp://127.0.0.1:8080/app nocanon

From the docs:

> Normally, mod_proxy will canonicalise ProxyPassed URLs. But this may be incompatible with some backends, particularly those that make use of PATH_INFO. The optional nocanon keyword suppresses this, and passes the URL path "raw" to the backend. Note that may affect the security of your backend, as it removes the normal limited protection against URL-based attacks provided by the proxy.