# Apache mod_proxy cuts off URLs at spaces

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have the following proxy rule on www.example.com/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.example.com/$1 [P]
```

Requests for

```
http://www.example.com/images/properties/resized%20pics/1_thumb.jpg
```

Are showing up in the server logs on www2 as

```
/images/properties/resized
```

I've tried various flags [NE,P], [B,P] but can't get this to work.  Also tried quoting the second argument of RewriteRule.  I've seen this question but it deals with 500 I'm getting 404.

[Apache 500 when proxying URLS with %20 via mod_proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/278325/apache-500-when-proxying-urls-with-20-via-mod-proxy)

```
tcpdump -A -s 0 port 80 and host www2.example.com | grep resized
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
E...%.@.t...I...l.s....Pu....<6.P.@).f..GET /images/properties/resized/ HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: I have tried your config and it does work for me as is (it sends `%20` to final server). As it is on 80 port, I'd suggest doing a `tcpdump -A -s 0 port 80 and host www2.example.com` to check if it is sending the correct petition and that it is not a log problem on www2.

Comment: I just noticed this is on Apache 2.2.9, could be the reason.  That is debian Lenny for those keeping track, at least it's not Etch.

Comment: Added tcpdump info to the question.  I think it's this bug but can't tell which version it's fixed in
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46428

Comment: Seems to be patched on `Apache 2.2.12`.

Comment: That's what I thought but I upgraded to 2.2.16-6+squeeze4~bpo50+1 from backports and still broke.  Frustrating..

Comment: Is it possible to move that config into apache's `.conf` files instead of `.htaccess`?